# Jenkins agent keeps disconnecting / reconnecting repeatedly

Tags: jenkins, agent

I have a jenkins master server. I just created a new jenkins agent and launching it via Java Web Start in a ubuntu host. The agent connects successfully, but after some time it says "Terminated", then again after some time it says "Connected". And it keeps repeating like this throughout.

I am not even trying to run a build/job yet

Interestingly enough, this ubuntu agent and this jnlp and this java web start has been working fine for the last several weeks - even until a few hours ago. Now suddenly it's starting to disconnected and reconnect repeatedly like this.

```
JNLP agent connected from /116.68.205.58
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>Slave.jar version: 3.2
This is a Unix agent
ERROR: Connection terminated
java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:73)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2822)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
    at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:59)
ERROR: Failed to install restarter
hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:307)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:888)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:92)
    at ......remote call to Channel to /116.68.205.58(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1537)
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:172)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:821)
    at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.install(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:52)
    at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.access$000(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:33)
    at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller$1.call(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:39)
    at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller$1.call(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:36)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:73)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2822)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
    at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:59)
JNLP agent connected from /116.68.205.58
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>Slave.jar version: 3.2
This is a Unix agent
```

Comment: Did you Solved it ?

Answer (score 2):

Check the jenkins slave log for possible problems. Also, how is the Availability setting under the Jenkins node configuration page?

> Jenkins >> Manage Jenkins >> Manage Nodes >> your node >> Configure

I recently had a Windows slave with the same symptom and change the Availability from

> "Take this agent online when in demand, and offline when idle"

to

> "Keep this agent online as much as possible"

and it solved my problem, but you might have a different problem from the one I had. So I suggest first viewing the slave logs. If you can, post the log snippet here for further analysis.